# React error "./src/App.js Line 7: 'APIKEY' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I create a weather app with React.js from tutorial and now I'm stuck and can't solve this error **"./src/App.js   Line 7:  'APIKEY' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars"**. How can I fix this error?

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Titles from './components/titles';
import Form from './components/form';
import Weather from './components/weather';

const APIKEY = "0bfdbb5c40aa44b13478951b236a0625";

class WeatherApp extends React.Component {

getWeather = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const api_call= await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID={APIKEY}');
  const response = await api_call.json();
  console.log(response);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Titles/>
        <Form loadWeather={this.getWeather} />
        <Weather/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default WeatherApp;
```

Comment: Change this line   const api_call= await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID={APIKEY}');
with this one   const api_call= await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=${APIKEY}`);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the template literals.
So :

```
const api_call= await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=${APIKEY}`);
```

With the backtites and the $ sign.